# Django forms.ModelForm Failed lookup for key [form]

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm getting error with forms.ModelForm Failed lookup for key or empty form, any suggestions, please?

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /timesheets/
Failed lookup for key [form] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}, {'view': <django.views.generic.base.TemplateView object at 0x00000201195B1F50>}]
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import TimeSheet
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Submit, Row


class TimeSheetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TimeSheet
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimeSheetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'AddNewEntry'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
                Row('date_time_start',
                    'date_time_end',
                    'project_code',
                    'user',
                    'milage',
                    'project_type',
                    'activities',
                    'expenses',
                    Submit('submit', 'Submit')
                    )
        )
```

## add_timesheet.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div id="timesheet-form-container"
     class="d-none d-flex flex-row flex-nowrap justify-content-between">
    <form id="timesheet-form" method="post" class="w-100">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% crispy form %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

## views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import TimeSheetForm
from .models import TimeSheet


def add_timesheet(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TimeSheetForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return {'success': True}
    else:
        form = TimeSheetForm()

    return render(request, 'timesheets/add_timesheet.html', {'form': form})
```

## timesheets/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(
            template_name='timesheets/timesheets_main.html'),
         name='timesheets'),
    path('add_timesheet/', views.add_timesheet, name='add_timesheet'),
    path('get_timesheets/', views.get_timesheets, name='get_timesheets'),
]
```

I`m tried to make a view class

## views.py

```
class AddTimeSheetView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'timesheets/add_timesheet.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print("get_context_data is called")  # Для отладки
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = TimeSheetForm()
        return context
```

## urls.py

```
  path('add_timesheet/', AddTimeSheetView.as_view(), name='add_timesheet'),
```

and it`s not working...

I tried also replacing {% crispy form %} to {{ form|crispy }}:

no errors but empty form.